# UNION syntax in Cakephp

Tags: php, sql, mysql, cakephp, union

Anyone knows a good way to make UNION query in CakePHP? I would like to avoid using `$this->query();`.

With two tables t1, t2:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

With three tables t1, t2, t3:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
RIGHT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you wish to avoid $this->query?

Comment: Well, for one, it defeats the purpose of using a framework if you're not going to try to write an application in the framework's native style. And most `SELECT` queries can in fact be carried out using `find()` in 1.3. Also, `find()` benefits from the data source drivers' built-in protection against SQL injections, whereas `query()` is a direct query that you'd have to escape yourself. That said, `UNION` is probably one of the few classes of queries you can't execute using `find()`.

Comment: Do you have a valid MySQL union example you are running? The one listed does not work.

Comment: I think there is some confusion as to the purpose of a framework. A framework is not necessarily design to make your code cross-database compatible. Furthermore, you should not limit the functionality of your site do to limitations within the framework. A framework is designed to separate the UI from domain logic. It also enhances development by bringing structure and organization and provides reusable code. You will limit what your capabilities are if you only did those things a framework allows.

Comment: @cdburges: I do not have the working example yet. In fact I need to do `FULL JOIN` but MySQL does not support that. So, I thought that I am not the first with this problem and the solution may be found already therefore I posted the question.

Comment: @stoosh: to make the query database independent.

Comment: No one said anything about limiting the functionality of your site. SQL queries can often be refactored (Bohemian gives one possibility). Likewise, application functionality can be implemented in different ways. If the framework you're using advocates one way of doing things (and is optimized for that) then you should try to do it in that way. Otherwise, you should consider using a more appropriate framework for your style of development.

Comment: I am sure it is possible to achieve what I want with CakePHP. I am just looking for the best way to do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Too many coders try to limit themselves to the functionality of a framework. DON'T. Use what the framework provides. If it does not have the functionality you seek, then either:

- Code the functionality you need into a class extension

or

- Custom spin the code within the framework to suit your needs.

Often, developers try to hammer a square peg into a round hole and wind up doing way too much extra work that really only makes the code complicated. Take a step back and ask why you are using the framework to begin with. It brings structure to an unstructured language. It provides solid reusable foundation to build your application on. It is not intended to be a box to put yourself in and be limited.

UPDATE: I took a minute to read [Complex Find Conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions) and found your answer:

```
$joins = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'test_twos',
        'alias' => 'TestTwo',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'TestTwo.id = TestOne.id',
        )
    ),
    array(
        'table' => 'test_threes',
        'alias' => 'TestThree',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
        'TestThree.id = TestOne.id',
    )
    )
);

$dbo = $this->getDataSource();
$subQuery = $dbo->buildStatement(
    array(
        'fields' => array('*'),
        'table' => $dbo->fullTableName($this),
        'alias' => 'TestOne',
        'limit' => null,
        'offset' => null,
        'joins' => $joins,
        'conditions' => null,
        'order' => null,
        'group' => null
    ),
    $this->TestOne
);
$query = $subQuery;

$query .= ' UNION ';
$joins = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'test_twos',
        'alias' => 'TestTwo',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'TestTwo.id = TestOne.id',
        )
    ),
    array(
        'table' => 'test_threes',
        'alias' => 'TestThree',
        'type' => 'RIGHT',
        'conditions' => array(
        'TestThree.id = TestOne.id',
        )
    )
);

$dbo = $this->getDataSource();
$subQuery = $dbo->buildStatement(
    array(
    'fields' => array('*'),
    'table' => $dbo->fullTableName($this),
    'alias' => 'TestOne',
    'limit' => null,
    'offset' => null,
    'joins' => $joins,
    'conditions' => null,
    'order' => null,
    'group' => null
    ),
    $this->TestOne
);

$query .= $subQuery;

pr($query);
```

Comment: The first thing to do is to check if it is possible to resolve a problem with the framework's functionality. Of course, the framework must not limit a programmer.

Comment: +1 for the update. That is the right direction. I will take a closer look at the code later.

Comment: Thumbs up for recommending that developers don't limit themselves to the functionality provided by the framework. I see way too many times where people dismiss a perfectly valid solution because "It's not the Cake Way."

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to do this, which we currently use, is to create a view in MySQL or whatever database you use. Then, instead of using a table in your model, you use your view. You can read about view creation syntax here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html. You could also use software like HeidiSQL to help you with view creation.

You would then have something like this in your model :

```
class Contenu extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'v_contenu';
```

This allows you to still use the `find()` method in CakePHP, which is really nice to have.

To get the best performance with views you should update MySQL to at least version 5.6.

Comment: This is a really nice solution

Answer (score 3):

Use a view, then select from that:

```
create view my_union as
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
RIGHT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
```

In your code:

```
select * from my_union
```

Comment: This is a good possible solution, but see this disclaimer on using views in Cake: http://www.mail-archive.com/cake-php@googlegroups.com/msg43116.html

Comment: I am afraid that would not work in other databases like SQLlite.

Comment: @bancer: are you sure about that? SQLite's documentation indicates that it supports views and uses the same `create view` syntax.

Comment: I meant `RIGHT JOIN`. Maybe my queries are bad at all to be database independent?

Answer (score 1):

use a code like this :

```
$friendsPosts= $this->Posts->find('all')
                ->contain(['Users', 'Languages', 'PostStates'])
                ->innerJoinWith('Users.Dusers', function ($q) {
                    return $q->where(['Dusers.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')]);
                });

        $posts= $this->Posts->find('all')
                ->where(['Posts.post_state_id' => 3])
                ->contain(['Users', 'Languages', 'PostStates']);

    $posts->union($friendsPosts);
```