# How can I do sql union in cake php?

Tags: sql, cakephp, union

I have to get all the associative data for the model. Basically the UNION query is as below:

```
  SELECT * FROM `videos` AS `U1` 
  WHERE `U1`.`level_id` = '1' AND `U1`.`submitted_date` > '2011-09-11'
UNION 
  SELECT * FROM `videos` AS `U2`
  WHERE `U2`.`level_id` = '1' AND `U2`.`submitted_date` < '2011-09-11'
  ORDER BY  submitted_date DESC
  LIMIT 0,10
```

So when I use 
`$this->Video->find('all')-->` I get all the result of the associated table datas.

Now I want to use the UNION SQL query and that should return associated table data too...

Any ideas how to use the cake inbuilt function to get data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in 4 or more different ways... the easiest but not recomended is using

```
$this->Model->query($query);
```

where `$query` is the query stated above.

The second way but may not be what you want, is to redo your sql query you will get same result (but not separated with the alias) like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `videos` AS `U1` 
WHERE `U1`.`level_id` = '1' AND (`U1`.`submitted_date` > '2011-09-11' OR `U1`.`submitted_date` < '2011-09-11')
ORDER BY  submitted_date DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

This query can be easily done with find like this

```
$conditions = array(
    'Video.level_id'=>1,
    'OR' => array(
        'Video.submitted_date <'=> '2011-09-11',
        'Video.submitted_date >'=> '2011-09-11'
    )
);
$this->Video->find('all', array('conditions'=>$conditions))
```

The third way will be the one that Abba Bryant talk about, explained in detail here [Union syntax in cakePhp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536107/union-syntax-in-cakephp) that works building the statement directly.

The fourth way will like the first one more less, you will have to create a behaviour that have a beforeFind function and there you will have to check if a option union and create the query or to create something like the the third option.

you will call it with a find like this

```
$this->Video->find('all', array('conditions'=>$conditions, 'union'=> $union));
```

This will be something more less like the linkable or containable behavior.

The fith way is to modified your cakephp sql driver... this one, i don't really know the changes you have to do, but it is a way to get to that... This drivers are the responsible to interpret and create the queries, connect to db and execute the queries...

REMEMBER that cakephp  find do the checks neccesary to prevent SQLInyection and other risks... the `$model->query` will NOT do this tests so be carefull

Comment: Thanks for the information of 4 types. Actually what I want to show is that:- The first union query should search for the videos which has maximum comments within the last 4 days i.e. showing the videos which has number of comments in descending order. And the second  union query will search for the videos which has maximum comments for the rest of the videos. AM i clear now ?

Comment: So the query now stand as  [[   SELECT * FROM `videos` AS `U1` 
  WHERE `U1`.`level_id` = '1' AND `U1`.`submitted_date` > '2011-09-11' ORDER BY comments DESC
UNION 
  SELECT * FROM `videos` AS `U2`
  WHERE `U2`.`level_id` = '1' AND `U2`.`submitted_date` < '2011-09-11'
  ORDER BY  comments DESC
  LIMIT 0,10    ]]

Comment: @saikat as i told you before you can do this with one of the methods above, or you can do it in two different select, remember not to be limited to the framework but also remember to do what the framework does for you (the sqlinyection test, etc). Also you should use <= or >= in one of those, if not you will miss a day.

Comment: I re-read your sql queries, and you don't get to use the union more than to unite results. So it is perfectly acceptable to do the two queries separated and then merge the results... (using array_merge_recursive or something like that might work)

Comment: Thanks but merging of results works fine with array_merge, and it is fine. But now the problem is the pagination. how should I carry out the pagination. what should be the offset in the second page of pagination in both the queries... i am a bit confused.... can you please help

Comment: well, thats a bit more complicated... since you have 2 queries and need to define if you want 10 from the first one and none from te second one, 5 from each of them or maybe all from the first and 10 from the second one. Anycase you should look this [Custom Query Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1237/Custom-Query-Pagination)

Answer (score 0):

This question here uses joins and the some direct datasource access to build a union query that can be used via the find method.

It is a bit of work, and the code won't be 100% appropriate for you - you will have to modify it - but it should get you started.

[UNION syntax in Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536107/union-syntax-in-cakephp)