# find entries to the left and right of a certain entry in a mysql table in a single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Let's say I have a table in a database like [this table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1aaf/11). Let's say that I want to get the entries on the left and right of the entry whose the primary key is equal to 5 (or any other primary key). So in our case, I want to get the entries whose primary key is equal to 4 and 6 respectively. What is the SQL query that will give me such result? Can you guys translate the SQL query into a [find('all')](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#find-all) CakePHP query?

Thank you

**NOTE: The ids are not necessarily contiguous, meaning, they do not necessarily follow the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 sequence. I can have something like 1, 5, 13, 44, 66, 123, etc**

Answer (score 3):

Try Union like this

```
 (SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id < 5 order by id DESC LIMIT 1)
 UNION
 (SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id >5  LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Good, but now how do you translate that to CakePHP find()?

Comment: Thanks, By the way I haven't worked on cakepgp but this links might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536107/union-syntax-in-cakephp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432065/how-can-i-do-sql-union-in-cake-php

Answer (score 1):

PHP

```
$id = 5;
SELECT * FROM Employee where id = $id-1 OR id = $id+1;
```

MySQL

```
SET @id = 5;
SELECT * FROM Employee where id = @id-1 OR id = @id+1;
```

Comment: What if my primary keys are something like `1, 5, 13, 44, 66, 123` ?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [find('neighbors')](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-neighbors). It returns the records before and after the one you specify and your ids can have "holes" in the sequence.