# using cakephp's find method for this complex SQL

Tags: sql, cakephp, orm, model

I want to use CakePHP's find method so I can take advantage of its model associations.  The problem is I have this complex SQL search and I don't know how to translate it into CakePHP's find method.  I've just been using $model->query() then using Set::extract on the IDs.  The problem is then I lose relevance order . How can I convert this to a find method in Cake so that I can use associations?

**SQL:**

```
SELECT id, title, SUM(relevance) as total_relevance FROM (
    SELECT 
        card_definitions.id, 
            card_definitions.title,
        (MATCH(card_definitions.title) AGAINST ('%s')) * 5 AS relevance
        FROM card_definitions
    UNION
    SELECT 
        card_definitions.id,
            card_definitions.title,
        (MATCH(card_def_identities.special_ability_text) AGAINST ('%s')) * 0.5 AS relevance
        FROM card_def_identities 
        INNER JOIN card_definitions ON card_def_identities.card_def_sid = card_definitions.id 
    UNION
    SELECT 
        card_definitions.id,
            card_definitions.title,
        (MATCH(brigades.brigade_color) AGAINST ('%s')) AS relevance
        FROM brigades 
        INNER JOIN card_def_brigades ON brigades.id = card_def_brigades.brigade_sid
        INNER JOIN card_definitions ON card_def_brigades.card_def_sid = card_definitions.id 
    UNION
    SELECT 
        card_definitions.id,
            card_definitions.title,
        (MATCH(identifiers.identifier) AGAINST ('%s')) AS relevance
        FROM identifiers
        INNER JOIN card_def_identifiers ON identifiers.id = card_def_identifiers.identifier_sid
        INNER JOIN card_definitions on card_def_identifiers.card_def_sid = card_definitions.id 
    UNION
    SELECT 
        card_definitions.id,
            card_definitions.title,
        (MATCH(card_effects.effect) AGAINST ('%s')) AS relevance
        FROM card_effects
        INNER JOIN card_def_effects ON card_effects.id = card_def_effects.effect_sid
        INNER JOIN card_definitions on card_def_effects.card_def_sid = card_definitions.id 
    ) AS combined_search 
GROUP BY id
HAVING total_relevance > 0
ORDER BY total_relevance DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

`%s` is replaced by the search query.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

Firstly, CakePHP doesn't support UNION's straight out of the...oven. If you wanted to recreate this in a cakey way without just dumping it in query(), you should take a look at Chucks solution where he manually creates the subqueries: [UNION syntax in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3538422/969807). Whilst this was written for Cake 1.2, it should point you in the right direction. The current docs on subqueries can be found here: book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries

Secondly, before embarking on a mission to shoehorn this query into Cake, as it looks like this query is used repeatedly without modification (its just a search right?) you may find that this is a good situation to use a stored procedure in your database. Once you have created your procedure you can just make a method in your model that calls it directly. Heres what the MySQL docs have to say: [Using Stored Routines (Procedures and Functions)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html)  but the process is even more trivial with tools like Adminer (adminer.org) or phpMyAdmin.

(Sorry about the URL pasting- I was limited to two actual links!)