# Querying multiple models for similar data in CakePHP (union?)

Tags: sql, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

So I have the following example tables:

```
Table A:
id
name
type
hat_size
created

Table B:
id
name
type
favorite_food
created

Table C:
id
name
type
some_other_thing
created
```

Let's say that I want to create a search with results from models `A`, `B`, and `C` using `id`, `name`, `type`, and `created`.

My goal would be to search all three tables, ordered by one of the fields (let's use `created` as the `ORDER_BY` field), and limited to say, 20 results.

Normally I would simply do a Union of these, order by the field, and `LIMIT` the result.

Now, I know I can just create a raw query to do this... but that means that I have to rewrite the paginate methods, always sanitize, etc.  Plus it's clunky and not necessarily portable across multiple SQL databases.  I'd prefer to do this a more MVC friendly way, using the models themselves, if possible.

What's the best way I can approach this with CakePHP?

Thank you,
James

Comment: CakePHP cant handle UNIONs very well. but it is possible - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536107/union-syntax-in-cakephp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a `VIEW` which holds the `UNION` query.  And then perform your Cake query on the view.

I'm starting to avoid views recently, however, because of the difficulty in transferring them between servers (and the annoying `DEFINER` command that is usually included in exports).

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, doesn't this also break the MVC structure?  I'd really like to hold to MVC, or it's sort of silly to use MVC to begin with.  I'm wondering if there's simply not a way that is MVC correct to accomplish this without brute-forcing a query and breaking some of the cake magic.

Comment: Well you create the view inside the database and then just use the view as your model.  I don't think that breaks MVC, but it is slightly fiddly...