# Use ORM methods in Cake Php to perform Union Operation on Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, orm

I am working on Cake PHP and need help on ORM methods. I have three tables- company, school and hospital. I want to generate a report which will have three rows where each row will correspond to the above three tables respectively.

Now for getting data from these 3 tables, I am doing a SQL UNION Query which fetches the data required  to show on the report.

Following is my SQL UNION Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, SUM(revenue) FROM company

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT name, SUM(revenue) FROM school 

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT name, SUM(revenue) FROM hospital
```

This works fine.

But my problem here is I need to use ORM methods to perform this operation. I am not supposed to write an SQL query, I need to write ORM methods to achieve the same.

Can any one suggest me how to convert this SQL query to ORM Method in Cake PHP? I have tried using query builder but I have not been able to successfully use it. Any help is really appreciable.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536107/union-syntax-in-cakephp

Comment: Thanks @ndm for reminding me that. I am working on CakePhP 2.5.

Comment: In that case it's really a duplicate. Checkout CakePHP 3.x for a more comfortable way to [**make use of unions**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#more-complex-queries).